# How to make custom C code into a SwiftPM package?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager

**I am trying to package C code into a Swift module**, let's call it *CModule*. Once I have put it into the base folder of a project (*SwiftModule*) and configured the Search Paths, I could get auto-complete to work in the Swift files, as well as detect errors/warnings.

The problem is, it won't recognize the module when it's imported, and *Jump to Definition* results in the following error:

```
Couldn't Generate Swift Representation

Error (from SourceKit):
"Could not load module: CModule"
```

**CModule contains the following files**:

- **src folder**, containing the implementation and an umbrella header exposing all required functions (by importing other sub-headers) such
  that *main_header.h* imports *componentA.h*, *componentB.h* etc
- **module.modulemap**, containing only:

```
module CModule [system] {
  header "src/main_header.h"
  export *
}
```

**The CModule folder is then put at the root of the SwiftModule project.**

The framework and import search paths are defined as follows: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/CModule (recursive)`

Considering auto-complete and others work, I am confident the import search path is set correctly. No idea about the framework search path.

*Additional details:*

- There are no spaces anywhere in my paths.
- *SwiftModule* is a "framework" that will eventually be put on CocoaPods.
- There are **no public headers** but the base *SwiftModule* header. *CModule* headers are all defined as Project headers.

Comment: What a problem just to create correct `Package.swift` file is you have sources? Don't need to touch `modulemap` file. It's content is SPM responsibility.

Comment: Doing it with Package.swift still results in the imported module not being recognized (no such module), but now not even autocomplete or errors/warnings work.
Essentially a step back.