# Swift Package: Module not found

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager

I have created a **non-syslib C module** (let's call it *CModule*) and packaged it with **Swift Package Manager** such that my code is in `$(package_directory)/Sources/CModule` and my `Package.swift` in the aforementioned parent directory contains:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CModule",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "CModule",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["CModule"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CModule",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources",
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("CModule")])
    ]
)
```

The package compiles without errors, but after adding it to another Swift project with `File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Dependency` and inputting the local repo (`file:///Users...etc`), which does give me the right target, doing `import CModule` within this new project gives me the *Module not found* error.

I have already relaunched Xcode, did *Clean Build Folder* followed by a normal *Build*, and tried another approach such as it was described in [How to make custom C code into a SwiftPM package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605987/how-to-make-custom-c-code-into-a-swiftpm-package)

Answer (score 3):

Try these steps:

**1. File -> Swift Packages -> Reset Package Caches**

After packages are reset, follow below steps:

**2. File -> Swift Packages -> Update to Latest Package Versions**